# How to re arrange array data from multiple arrays that are linked to create a multi dimensional array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have data from my DB as an array as follows.

```
["John", "Seth", "Eben"]["john@domain.gov.gh", "seth@domain.gov.gh", "eben@domain.gov.gh"]`["0212225252", "0201115555", "0201115556"]`
```

They are different arrays but the data is linked to each other ie: name, email, phone
I want to re-arrange this array into a multi-dimensional array but with the proper relation between the arrays. example

```
["John", "john@domain.gov.gh", "0212225252"]

["Seth", "seth@domain.gov.gh", "0201115555"]
```

and so on...

I have tried so many different options of push and merge but I guess my skills in javascript are not up to the task. And also the resulting data is going to be displayed in an HTML table. That part I have already sorted out with some test dummy data.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You could for-loop though and build object/arrays for the current iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop for this:

```js
let names = ["John", "Seth", "Eben"];
let emails = ["john@domain.gov.gh", "seth@domain.gov.gh",
"eben@domain.gov.gh"];
let phones = ["0212225252", "0201115555", "0201115556"];

let matrix = [];
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  matrix.push([names[i], emails[i], phones[i]]);
}

console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: I think I'd like to wrap it in an if to check all the arrays were the same length, eg ```lang-js if(names.length === emails.length && names.length === phones.length){
    //funtion here.
}
 ```

Comment: Yeah that's okay too, in my case this will almost never happen because data is from a form that has both front end and back end validate of these fields that are required, and the form will never submit if any of these are empty. But then again I have implemented nullish and undefined check on each field will displaying before showing in the html table so all is good.

Answer (score 1):

assuming same index from each array will always be related.

```js
let names = ["John", "Seth", "Eben"],
  emails = ["john@domain.gov.gh", "seth@domain.gov.gh", "eben@domain.gov.gh"],
  phones = ["0212225252", "0201115555", "0201115556"],
  array = [];

for (const i in names) {
  array.push([names[i], emails[i], phones[i]]);
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = ["John", "Seth", "Eben"]
const b = ["john@domain.gov.gh", "seth@domain.gov.gh", "eben@domain.gov.gh"]
const c = ["0212225252", "0201115555", "0201115556"]

function mixin(a, b, c) {
  const names = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
  const emails = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
  const tels = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));
  return names.map((item, index) => [item, emails[index], tels[index]])
}

console.log(mixin(a, b, c))
```

Comment: What is the point of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))`? Surely that will just return a new copy of each array, which seems unnecessary since you never modify any of the passed in arrays.